# Не получается понять где ошибка

Tags: python

Прога работает нормально, но до момента когда идет поиск. Если нажать ctrl + f в браузере, то будет поиск. Я решил сделать также, но ищется у меня только слово "Это" (самое первое), даже если я написал слово которого в тексте нету. Вот мой ультра-корявый код:

```
import time

print("Привет, это тест поиска. Просто нажми ctrl + f")
print("Это текст. Читая его, вы пополняете свой мозг новой информацией. Но, есть и старая информация, обычно это что-то вроде молоко белое. Вы можете поискать что-нибудь в этом тексте, если вы не знаете то прочитайте текст выше. Спасибо за внимание")

a = "Это текст. Читая его, вы пополняете свой мозг новой информацией. Но, есть и старая информация, обычно это что-то вроде молоко белое. Вы можете поискать что-нибудь в этом тексте, если вы не знаете то прочитайте текст выше. Спасибо за внимание"
words = a.split(" ")

keyboard.wait("Ctrl + F")

for x in words: # Вот здесь начинается звиздец
    k = input("Введите какое-либо слово из текста: ")
    l = x.find(k)
    if "n" != -1:
        print("Слово, которые вы нашли: " + str(x) )
    else:
        print("Вы неправильно ввели слово")
    time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ошибку(если вам Python пишет кракозябры), либо же более конкретно объясните что должен делать ваш код

Comment: Для чего тут цикл? Почему не `words.find(k)`? Почему не `if l != -1`? Что такое str?

Comment: 1) Код должен просто сделать поиск слов, типо чувак введет слово, и оно будет искаться, если не найдется то напишет что нифига не найдено, если найдется то напишет все слова которые начинаются или повторяются на то что написал чувак.

Comment: `"n" != -1` - истинное утверждение. Что вы тут хотели сравнить?

Comment: 2) Либо я тупой, либо здесь нету цикла. Если написать words.find то команды будут искать слова что там написано, тоесть если я напишу эту команду и напишу "это" (из текста в 4 строке) то я ничего не найду, так как слова ищутся в строке `a.split(" ")` . На 3 вопрос я не отвечу, так как слился, а на 4 (самый тупой)... str это строка

Comment: time.sleep(600) этоже 600 секунд. 10 минут между итерациями это перебор. попробуйте без этой строки

Comment: @интик Я эту строку сделал чтобы когда уже в ехе файле там не закрывалось, тоесть в конце каждого кода если нет команд на замарохку код просто перестанет работать

Comment: А, я хз если честно откуда цикл) Наверн из-за keyboard, если я уберу time нафиг то у меня будет писаться по слову, тоесть если текст будет "Я крутой", то мне выдадет сначала "Я", а во 2 раз уже "крутой"

Comment: *сделай лучше input() в конце.будет ждать нажатия энтэра.удобнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо вашего

```
for x in words: # Вот здесь начинается звиздец
    k = input("Введите какое-либо слово из текста: ")
    l = x.find(k)
    if "n" != -1:
        print("Слово, которые вы нашли: " + str(x) )
    else:
        print("Вы неправильно ввели слово")
    time.sleep(600)
```

используйте

```
k = input("Введите какое-либо слово из текста: ")
if k in words:
    print("Слово, которые вы нашли: " + k )
else:
    print("Вы неправильно ввели слово")
```

Comment: Перед поиском, ещё нужно было бы убрать точки и запятые, а то слова будут деффектными.